# Fastlane build_app (gym) error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found

Tags: ios, fastlane, ad-hoc-distribution, code-signing-certificate

I'm using Fastlane to build and distribute my iOS (React Native) app but running into issues getting the build to work with [build_app](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/build_app/) (gym).

I am running into this error (I've replaced the real team ID):

```
❌  error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "R111111111" with a private key was found. (in target 'ButtonApp' from project 'ButtonApp')
```

Here is the summary for the gym action:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|                                Summary for gym 2.199.0                                |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| project                                           | ButtonApp.xcodeproj               |
| scheme                                            | ButtonApp                         |
| clean                                             | true                              |
| export_method                                     | ad-hoc                            |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.buttonapp | com.buttonapp AdHoc               |
| build_path                                        | ./builds                          |
| output_directory                                  | ./builds                          |
| output_name                                       | ButtonApp                         |
| silent                                            | false                             |
| skip_package_ipa                                  | false                             |
| skip_package_pkg                                  | false                             |
| result_bundle                                     | false                             |
| buildlog_path                                     | ~/Library/Logs/gym                |
| destination                                       | generic/platform=iOS              |
| skip_profile_detection                            | false                             |
| xcodebuild_command                                | xcodebuild                        |
| skip_package_dependencies_resolution              | false                             |
| disable_package_automatic_updates                 | false                             |
| use_system_scm                                    | false                             |
| xcode_path                                        | /Users/attila/Downloads/Xcode.app |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Build environment:

```
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
|                 Build environment                 |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Users/attila/Downloads/Xcode.app |
| gym_version   | 2.199.0                           |
| export_method | ad-hoc                            |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS15.0.sdk                  |
+---------------+-----------------------------------+
```

The get_certificates, get_provisioning_profile, update_project_provisioning, and update_project_team actions run fine with no errors. Looking at my keychain, under "My Certificates" on the login keychain, I do in fact have an iPhone Distribution certificate (with my corresponding team ID) and it has a private key.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by manually selecting the provisioning profile in Xcode that I'm targeting in my Fastfile. In Xcode, select your app -> Signing & Capabilities -> Signing, and from there select the corresponding provisioning profile in the dropdown.